# How to set height to wrap content in the adapter

Tags: android, android-adapter

Is there a way to set layout height to wrap content on the adapter?
The layout that I inflate in my adapter has two parts. One of the parts is visible while the other one is gone, but both of them has wrap_content for the height. Like:

```
<LinearLayout
...
android:visibility="gone" >
  <View
  ...
  android:visibility="visible" />
  <View
  ...
  android:visibility="gone" />
<LinearLayout>
```

Now, with a press of a button, the second view's visibility will be set to visible. But problem is that it doesn't wrap it's content. The height it only uses is the height from the first view, the one who's already visible.

I tried to set:

```
view.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

next after I set the view's visibility to visible, but it did not work.

So, is there a way? Or can you suggest any workaround? Thank you so much.

Comment: Are you setting the parent `LinearLayout` visibility to `VISIBLE`? If so, then it will set it's height based on the first `View` since only that one is visible. If you want it to stretch it's height to use the second `View` height as well, set the second `View` visibility to `INVISIBLE`.

Comment: I know. but it is in a listview, so having the second View set to INVISIBLE would not look nice.

Comment: On the button click, it's the `LinearLayout` that will become visible., right? After it becomes visible it's height is set the same amount as the first `View`. This happens because the second `View` is still `gone`. If you don't want to show the `View` but make `LinearLayout` wrap it's content `invisible` is the way to go. The only other way the `LinearLayout` will grow its height is if both `View` are `visible`.

Comment: No, sorry if I misled somewhere. But what i'm trying to set to visible is the second view, inside the LinearLayout. Actually I am able to set the second View to Visible, but the height that the LinearLayout is based from the first View which is already visible. I know that i set it to visible because I can scroll the LinearLayout to see the second View. But if you're saying that I can't shift it from gone to visible, then I guess I have to find a work around. Thank you.

Comment: You can shift from `gone` to `visible`, I just couldn't clearly understand the question, which is why I'm commenting instead of answering. I think you need to programmatically scroll your `ListView` to show the `LinearLayout` in full. Perhaps [ListView.smoothScrollByOffset](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#smoothScrollByOffset%28int%29) could be of help. Use second `View` height as the `offset`.

Comment: Finally found the answer. Stupid me. I set the ListView height to wrap content instead of match parent. Thanks, man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was that the bug was with the developer. Haha. I set the ListView's height to wrap content instead of match parent.

Comment: just try to log and count how many times your items create in a listview which has height =  "wrap_content"